# Is there a default or required filename and location for an Open Search file?

Tags: search, xml, site-search

Is there a default/required filename for the [Open Search](http://www.opensearch.org/Home)? Like `search.xml` or `opensearch.xml` or is every name allowed as long as the reference from the HTML `link`-tag is correct?

Also, can it only be placed in the public root folder `/` or in any subfolder as long as the reference is correct?

Comment: Funny. I do not see any info on where to put the files. I assume within the web root directory. Sorry. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the standard the open search document can be placed anywhere under your web directory as long as it can be accessed by URL and you simply add the open search meta block to each page linking to the open search description file. True common practice is to name it open search.XML and to place it in the web root but the standard does not require this.